# Is there a way to get the URL of the localised version of a product variant?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have a website that uses Craft Commerce and I'm trying to add a language menu that points to the localised version of each product variant as follows:

```
  {% set variantID = craft.request.getParam('variant') %}
  {% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocales() %}

  {% for locale in locales %}
     {% set localisedEntryUrl = craft.commerce.variants.id(variantID).locale(locale.id).first().url() %}
     {{ localisedEntryUrl }}
  {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the code above always produces the variant url for one language. eg.

```
/en/shop/ornaments/melisa?variant=9356
/en/shop/ornaments/melisa?variant=9356
/en/shop/ornaments/melisa?variant=9356
```

whereas I would expect something like:

```
/en/shop/ornaments/melisa?variant=9356
/de/shop/ornaments/melisa?variant=9356
/es/shop/ornaments/melisa?variant=9356
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
{% set variantID = craft.request.getParam('variant') %}
{% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds() %}

{% for locale in locales %}
    {% if variantID is defined %}
        {% set localisedEntryUrl = craft.commerce.variants.id(variantID).locale(locale).first %}
        {% if localeEntry.locale == locale %}
            {{ localisedEntryUrl.getUrl() }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! Unfortunately, this code produces the error: `Variable "localeEntry" does not exist.` If you meant entry.locale I tried it and it didn't work. Still produces the same link for all locales.